# Eagerloading Many-to-Many related data

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity framework core. 
I have a many-to-many relationsship between ComponentType and Category

ComponentType model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace embeddedstock.Models
{
    public class ComponentType
    {
        public ComponentType()
        {
            Components = new List<Component>();
            CategoryComponentType = new List<CategoryComponentType>();
        }
        public long ComponentTypeId { get; set; }
        public string ComponentName { get; set; }
        public string ComponentInfo { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public ComponentTypeStatus Status { get; set; }
        public string Datasheet { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public string WikiLink { get; set; }
        public string AdminComment { get; set; }
        public virtual ESImage Image { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Component> Components { get; protected set; }
        public ICollection<CategoryComponentType> CategoryComponentType { get; protected set; }

    }

 }
```

Category model

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace embeddedstock.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        public Category()
        {
            CategoryComponentType = new List<CategoryComponentType>();
        }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<CategoryComponentType> CategoryComponentType { get; protected set; }
    }
 }
```

Pivot table/model

```
namespace embeddedstock.Models
{
    public class CategoryComponentType
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }

        public long ComponentTypeId { get; set; }
        public ComponentType ComponentType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DB context

```
using embeddedstock.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace embeddedstock.Contexts
{
    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options)
            :base(options) { }
        public DatabaseContext(){ }

        public DbSet<Component> Components { get; set; }

        public DbSet<ComponentType> ComponentTypes { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        public DbSet<ESImage> ESImages { get; set; }

        public DbSet<CategoryComponentType> CategoryComponentTypes { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<CategoryComponentType>()
                .HasKey(t => new { t.CategoryId, t.ComponentTypeId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<CategoryComponentType>()
                .HasOne(cpt => cpt.Category)
                .WithMany(c => c.CategoryComponentType)
                .HasForeignKey(cpt => cpt.CategoryId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<CategoryComponentType>()
                .HasOne(cpt => cpt.ComponentType)
                .WithMany(ct => ct.CategoryComponentType)
                .HasForeignKey(cpt => cpt.ComponentTypeId);
        }

    }
}
```

When I try this:

```
public IActionResult Show(int id)
{
    var Cat = DbContext.Categories.Include(x => x.CategoryComponentType).FirstOrDefault(y => y.CategoryId == id);

    Console.WriteLine(Cat.CategoryComponentType.Count);


    ViewBag.Category = Cat;

    return View();
}
```

It counts the correct numbers of related data, but i get this exception:

> RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
>   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , object )

The view related to this method: When I fetch a category that doesn't have any relation it works just fine.

```
@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Category"; } @model embeddedstock.Models.Category



<div class="">
  <div class="row">
    <h3 class="">@ViewBag.Category.Name</h3>

    <a asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Destroy" asp-route-id="@ViewBag.Category.CategoryId" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a> 
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>

<h3>Change category name</h3>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Store", "Category", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-body"})) {
    <div class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, null, new { @class= "col-md-4 control-label"})

        <div class="col-md-6 ">
          @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class= "form-control", @style=" width: 100%; max-width: 100%;", autofocus=""})
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 100%;">
                  Save
                </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    }
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not look like an error with your data model, but rather with your View that binds to the data at runtime.
Please post your View page, and/or all properties you show on the page exist and are not null.

Comment: @flip Just updated med Qs with the view - thank you.

Comment: It seems like you need to validate if entity is null or not before to try read the value from CategoryComponent.Count, Also I see you don't send model to view, you are setting your "model" object into ViewBag, that's correct?

Comment: @H.Herzi Yes that is correct. I access my model in view from viewbag

Comment: No, I mean validate in controller